# Binding Different LINQ datasource using same variable w/ if statement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

OK So I know WHY I am having the error I am getting. I don't know HOW to fix it. Basically, if the user doesn't have a certain permission, I need to join another table. But .NET is so picky I can't just make two different queries in an IF statement and then use it outside of the if statement. I can think of some ugly work arounds for this, but I would rather not. I am fairly new to .NET I know just enough to be dangerous.

```
Private Sub loadLeads()
        Using db As New CRMDataDataContext(SQLConnectionString)
            Dim count = 0
            Dim l As IEnumerable(Of Company)
            If CanViewAllLeads(User.Identity.Name, db) = True Then
                Dim q = From leads In db.Companies _
                        Join s In db.CompanySources On s.CompanySourceID Equals leads.CompanySourceID _
                        Where leads.Active = True And leads.CompanyStatusID = 1 _
                        Select leads.CompanyID, _
                                leads.BusinessName, _
                                leads.Website, _
                                leads.Phone, _
                                leads.Fax, _
                                leads.LastContacted, _
                                leads.FollowUp, _
                                leads.CreatedBy, _
                                leads.Created, _
                                leads.UpdatedBy, _
                                leads.Updated, _
                                Source = s.Source
                count = q.Count
                l = q
            Else
                Dim q = From leads In db.Companies _
                    Join s In db.CompanySources On s.CompanySourceID Equals leads.CompanySourceID _
                    Join xref In db.UserCompaniesXrefs On leads.CompanyID Equals xref.CompanyID _
                    Where leads.Active = True And leads.CompanyStatusID = 1 And xref.UserID = NCGuid(User.Identity.Name) _
                    Select leads.CompanyID, _
                            leads.BusinessName, _
                            leads.Website, _
                            leads.Phone, _
                            leads.Fax, _
                            leads.LastContacted, _
                            leads.FollowUp, _
                            leads.CreatedBy, _
                            leads.Created, _
                            leads.UpdatedBy, _
                            leads.Updated, _
                            Source = s.Source
                count = q.Count
                l = q
            End If
            If count > 0 Then
                dgLeads.DataSource = l
                dgLeads.DataBind()
            Else
                pnlLeads.Visible = False
                pnlNoLeads.Visible = True
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

I get the error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_1`11[System.Guid,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.Guid],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable`1[System.Guid],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Ten11CRMLib.Company]'.

because of this: Dim l As IEnumerable(Of Company) its not just IEnumerable of a Company, its got the source in it. I have to explicitly select source to use it in my datagrid. Can I make Dim l something that will make it stop complaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Aliostad said just bind q, I knew that wouldn't work but realized l was being redundant. Since I was making explicit selects and selecting the same thing from both queries, instead of selecting * (which is what I was doing when I had it IEnumerable(of Company)) I just Dim q IEnumerable outside of the if statement. I am not really sure if selecting explicitly vs all has any effect on the generic IEnumerable work. I lost the ability to use q.count in doing that, but I found a different solution for that as you can see in the code that works below:

```
Private Sub loadLeads()
        Using db As New CRMDataDataContext(SQLConnectionString)
            Dim q As IEnumerable
            If CanViewAllLeads(User.Identity.Name, db) = True Then
                q = From leads In db.Companies _
                        Join s In db.CompanySources On s.CompanySourceID Equals leads.CompanySourceID _
                        Where leads.Active = True And leads.CompanyStatusID = 1 _
                        Select leads.CompanyID, _
                                leads.BusinessName, _
                                leads.Website, _
                                leads.Phone, _
                                leads.Fax, _
                                leads.LastContacted, _
                                leads.FollowUp, _
                                leads.CreatedBy, _
                                leads.Created, _
                                leads.UpdatedBy, _
                                leads.Updated, _
                                Source = s.Source
            Else
                q = From leads In db.Companies _
                    Join s In db.CompanySources On s.CompanySourceID Equals leads.CompanySourceID _
                    Join xref In db.UserCompaniesXrefs On leads.CompanyID Equals xref.CompanyID _
                    Where leads.Active = True And leads.CompanyStatusID = 1 And xref.UserID = NCGuid(User.Identity.Name) _
                    Select leads.CompanyID, _
                            leads.BusinessName, _
                            leads.Website, _
                            leads.Phone, _
                            leads.Fax, _
                            leads.LastContacted, _
                            leads.FollowUp, _
                            leads.CreatedBy, _
                            leads.Created, _
                            leads.UpdatedBy, _
                            leads.Updated, _
                            Source = s.Source
        End If
        If q.Cast(Of Company).Count > 0 Then
            dgLeads.DataSource = q
            dgLeads.DataBind()
        Else
            pnlLeads.Visible = False
            pnlNoLeads.Visible = True
        End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting back a custom class - an **anonymous type**. This cannot be casted back to your `Customer` object.

If you really need to do that, create a converter method (or perhaps put it on constructor) and pass the object and initialise the values from your anonymous type. Use **dynamic** as the type of object.

Comment: I apologize, again I am new to .net, could you provide me resources or documentation on what I need to do, you went a bit over my head. I think you are saying I will have to have Dim l be anonymous, and then send it to a method that will cast it to what I need it to be?

Comment: Why just not binding q itself? Do not assign q to l, just bind to q, that should work. Are u using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: No I am not using MVC unfortunately, I WANTED to, but alas, I was shot down. I am using webforms, and binding q doesn't work, hence l, it says q is not declared because it is declared in the if statement. One thing about .NET I really HATE. It's an if/else, its GOING to get declared, it won't even build if I just use q. BUT I did find a solution, at first I wasn't making explicit selections, then I realized I needed to. I will add the answer shortly.